# Django Wagtail/Haystack Search with Heroku

Tags: django, elasticsearch, heroku, wagtail

I uploaded my project to heroku and I have a Search engine which works on local development and I would like to make it work in production as well. I used Wagtails Search since it was super easy to install and configure but it seems not to be a proper solution for production. This was my configuration:

```
WAGTAILSEARCH_BACKENDS = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'wagtail.wagtailsearch.backends.elasticsearch5',
    'URLS': [u'http://localhost:9200'],
    'INDEX': 'wagtail',
    'TIMEOUT': 5,
    'OPTIONS': {},
    'INDEX_SETTINGS': {},
    "ATOMIC_REBUILD":True
  }
}
```

Heroku can't connect to Port 9200 and when I stated to read into the the configurations it seemed to be easier to use Haystack/Solr. This [Heroku Article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/searchbox) suggests to use the add-on "SearchBox Elasticsearch" but I cannot add any addons at the moment. So my Questions are:

1. Can I run the normal Haystack/Wagtail search without the Heroku add-on?
2. How do I make the 9200 Port accessible for Heroku?
3. Would it make sense to upgrade to Haystack? Is Wagtail scalable in production? anybody made any experience in production?

Im quite happy with Wagtail since everything works as it should and I don't want to change something that does the job. Hope somebody can enlighten me.

Comment: Your terminology is a bit mixed up here. "Wagtail search" describes several different configurations with one of three possible backends http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11/topics/search/backends.html - out of those backends, Elasticsearch and PostgreSQL are suitable for large-scale sites, but the database backend is not. Wagtail search currently has no backend for Haystack or Solr, so it's not clear what you mean by "the normal Haystack/Wagtail search".

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL, or is using PostgreSQL an option on Heroku? If so, I'd recommend using the PostgreSQL backend http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11/reference/contrib/postgres_search.html#postgres-search - it should be functionally close to what you get with Elasticsearch, but not require running an external service. (I don't know Heroku well, so I thought I'd better check before adding that as an answer...)

Comment: Yes im using Postgres and that just worked like a charm. Thank you so much for sharing the link. I can't believe I found that myself. Like I clicked through every link google spit out put apparently I searched for the wrong things. Anyway thanks a lot. If you want you can post that comment as an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PostgreSQL as your database, a good option is to use Wagtail's [PostgreSQL full-text search backend](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11/reference/contrib/postgres_search.html). It's fairly close in functionality to Elasticsearch, production-ready for large sites, and doesn't require running an external service.